# Any alternative to showing chat messages on android app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, chat

this is the chat functionality on my app but the messages aren't appearing on my app although it is getting updated in the firebase. when I hardcoded the values it is working. this is the conversation activity. I've used a chat fragment and adapter as well. But the messages are just not getting posted on the app. any alternative solutions or a solution for this would be nice.

```
   private val firebaseDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
   private val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
   private val conversationAdapter = ConversationAdapter(arrayListOf(), userId)
   private var chatId: String? = null
   private var imageUrl: String? = null
   private var otherUserId: String? = null
   private var chatName: String? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation)

       chatId = intent.extras.getString(PARAM_CHAT_ID)
       imageUrl = intent.extras.getString(PARAM_IMAGE_URL)
       chatName = intent.extras.getString(chatName)
       otherUserId = intent.extras.getString(PARAM_OTHER_USER_ID)

        if (chatId.isNullOrEmpty() || userId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "chat room error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            finish()
        }

        topNameTV.text = chatName
        populateImage(this, imageUrl, topPhotoIV, R.drawable.default_user)

        messagesRV.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(false)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = conversationAdapter
           }
         firebaseDB.collection(DATA_CHATS)
            .document(chatId!!)
            .collection(DATA_CHAT_MESSAGES)
           .orderBy(DATA_CHAT_MESSAGE_TIME)
           .addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                if(firebaseFirestoreException != null){
                    firebaseFirestoreException.printStackTrace()
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                  }else{
                       if (querySnapshot != null){
                        for(change in querySnapshot.documentChanges){
                            when(change.type){
                               DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                                   val message = change.document.toObject(Convo::class.java)
                                   if(message != null){
                                         conversationAdapter.addMessage(message)
                                         messagesRV.post {

   messagesRV.smoothScrollToPosition(conversationAdapter.itemCount -1)
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                          }
                       }
                   }
               }
          }
    }
       fun onSend(v: View) {

        if (!messageET.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
           val message = Convo(userId, messageET.text.toString(), System.currentTimeMillis())
            firebaseDB.collection(DATA_CHATS).document(chatId!!)
                .collection(DATA_CHAT_MESSAGES)
                .document()
                .set(message)
            messageET.setText("",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
             }

       }

       companion object {
          private val PARAM_CHAT_ID = "Chat id"
          private val PARAM_IMAGE_URL = "Image url"
          private val PARAM_OTHER_USER_ID = "Other user id"
          private val PARAM_CHAT_NAME = "Chat name"

          fun newIntent(context: Context?, chatId: String?, imageUrl: String?, otherUserId: String? 
         chatName: String?): Intent{
        val intent = Intent(context,ConversationActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_CHAT_ID,chatId)
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_IMAGE_URL, imageUrl)
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_OTHER_USER_ID, otherUserId)
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_CHAT_NAME, chatName)
        return intent
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can display messages in a Chat App using Cloud Firestore and Kotlin.

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: oh omg thats great. ill check it out. as of now when i send a message to another person and they send one back. it shows intantly in firebase but the messages are not appearing on the app :(

Comment: can I show you my code in detail? @AlexMamo

Comment: topNameTV.text = chatName this where the users name is supposed to show up on the chat page of the person your chatting with and the messages dont show

Comment: its actually a twitter clone app and im trying to add chat functionality

Comment: just like your tutorial even in my app you can message anyone in my contacts and whos on the app. but unfortunately the messages are not getting delivered to the user in the front end